# invoke error when trying to exit program

Tags: assembly, error-handling, x86, invoke

I have this code

```
restart:
            mov edx, OFFSET prompt5
            call WriteString
            mov edx, 0  
            mov edx , OFFSET buffer
            call ReadString
            cmp edx, 'n'  or 'N'
            JE exit
            cmp edx, 'Y'  or 'y'
            JE ReadInput
            JNE restart
```

This code is to ask user to enter either `Y` or `y` for yes. if they enter `Y` or `y` the program will start from the beginning, if user enter anything else beside `y` or `Y` and `n` or `N`. 
if user enter `n` or `N` the program exits.

why do i  get invoke error on `JE exit` line

thank in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare two values at the same time. When you do `cmp al, 'Y' or 'y'` the assembler will calculate the bitwise OR of `'Y'` and `'y'`, which is just `'y'`. So that instruction becomes the equivalent of `cmp al, 'y'`.

If you want to compare against both of those values, you need to do each comparison separately.

```
cmp al,'Y'
je L1
cmp al,'y'
je L1
```

Assuming `L1` is the label you want to jump to if the user enters Y or y. I'm basing this on the modified code in your answer - not the original code in your question.

Then, for the 'restart' case, you don't need to use `jne` - you can just use an unconditional `jmp`. If you've reached that point in the code, then you've already failed to match any of the other conditions, so you know the character is not equal to Y, y, N or n - no more testing required.

**Update**

I should add that I'm assuming the functions `WriteChar` and `Crlf` preserve the `al` register. Because if `ReadChar` returns the read character in `al`, but `WriteChar` or `Crlf` end up overwriting it with something else, this code is never going to work.

If `al` is not being preserved, you could save it temporarily on the stack by doing something like this:

```
call ReadChar
push eax
call WriteChar
call Crlf
pop  eax
cmp  al,'N'
...etc
```

Comment: Notice that he uses mov ax,0 to clear ax and cmp al,'y'. AX/EAX is the register which supplies the input/data to the call, not edx

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. The input/data to what call? The `WriteString` function assumedly writes the string in EDX, the `WriteChar` function assumedly writes the character in AL. I'm hoping `WriteChar` and `Crlf` and preserve AL, otherwise nothing would work. I'm making some assumptions here since we're only seeing part of the code, but I can certainly make this work by providing my own implementations for the missing functions.

Comment: He's at a very early stage of asm and using al is normally the register used for handling letters/numbers etc. I'm pointing that out to him. His original program only used edx

Comment: OK, but my answer is referring to his updated code, which is completely different. He is actually using al now.

Comment: "He is actually using al now." He is indeed(after copy/pasting your code), and not having a clue why. For you or me it's an automatic assumption, not for him though.

Comment: If you check the time on my answer and his, you'll see he updated his code before I gave my answer. I think he deserves a little more credit than you're giving him. :)

Comment: Look at posting hour i posted the code 3 hours before his answer , so how am i copy and paste his code?

Answer (score 0):

```
restart:
            mov eax, 0
            mov edx, OFFSET prompt5
            call WriteString
            mov edx, 0  
            call ReadChar
            call WriteChar
            call Crlf
            cmp al, 'N' 
            JE L
            cmp al, 'n'
            JE L
            cmp al, 'Y' or 'y'
            JE L1
            JNE restart

    L:
            exit
```

Comment: I' m almost getting it right, the code seem to work fine when enter n or N , but when i try to enter y or Y it does not do anything, how should i compare both Y and y to al register at the same time?